# Mysql Get Rank with Filters

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, ranking

I Have a marksheet table like:

```
ID  STUDENT_ID  Branch_id   Class_id    Exam_id Subject_id  Numbers     Date
1       653         5           1           1   8               60      2012-01-01
2       653         5           1           1   9               40      2012-01-01
3       653         5           1           1   10              80      2012-01-01
4       653         5           1           1   11              50      2012-01-01
5       653         5           1           1   12              65      2012-01-01
6       653         5           1           1   13              33      2012-01-01
7       653         5           1           1   15              86      2012-01-01
8       222         5           1           1   8               100     2012-01-01
9       222         5           1           1   9               80      2012-01-01
10      222         5           1           1   10              92      2012-01-01
11      222         5           1           1   11              50      2012-01-01
12      222         5           1           1   12              65      2012-01-01
13      222         5           1           1   13              33      2012-01-01
7       222         5           1           1   15              86      2012-01-01
```

I need to know the rank of student if one or more student equal in rank. and filter with branc and class id.

Can any one help me?

Comment: What do you mean "if one or more student equal in rank"? By rank, do you mean ID? Or ranked by the "numbers" column? Do you only want to get a result if any two students are equal in rank?

Comment: Yes I want to know result if two student are equal in marks. if two student get 600 marks out of 600 total marks that means they both are on first position. And that position depend on there marks sum of number column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID, Numbers, IF(@marks=(@marks:=Numbers), @auto, @auto:=@auto+1) rank 
FROM (SELECT STUDENT_ID, Branch_id, Class_id, SUM(Numbers) Numbers
      FROM quiz_user 
      GROUP BY STUDENT_ID 
      ORDER BY Numbers DESC, STUDENT_ID 
     ) AS A, (SELECT @auto:=0, @marks:=0) AS B
WHERE Branch_id = 5 AND Class_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(Numbers),STUDENT_ID,Branch_id,  Class_id
from marksheet 
where Branch_id='value' and Class_id='valueClass'
group by STUDENT_ID,Branch_id,  Class_id
order by sum(Numbers) desc
```

fiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4c39/1)

Comment: @zia do u have any trouble with this query??? then you can put comment for this instead of edit my answer. because otherwise other users may confuse with the answer

Comment: OK sorry for editing but I have't got answer when two students equal in marks.

Comment: @zia- i have modified the fiidle answer- please check it here... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4c39/1 according to that it works properly. if not what sort of out put do u expect?

Comment: Sir Your example work fine but you can see ID # 222 on second row when I assign a rank in class it will be second (like when come in while loop and assign rank by $i or whatever) but it is wrong because ID #222 is also on first position.

Comment: @Zia: Could you just update your question with the desired output for your particular example?