# mysql pivot query and rank Query

Tags: mysql, pivot, rank

I Have a marksheet table like:

```
ID  STUDENT_ID  Branch_id   Class_id    Exam_id Subject_id  Numbers     Date
1       653         5           1           1   8               60      2012-01-01
2       653         5           1           1   9               40      2012-01-01
3       653         5           1           1   10              80      2012-01-01
4       653         5           1           1   11              50      2012-01-01
5       653         5           1           1   12              65      2012-01-01
6       653         5           1           1   13              33      2012-01-01
7       653         5           1           1   15              86      2012-01-01
8       222         5           1           1   8               100     2012-01-01
9       222         5           1           1   9               80      2012-01-01
10      222         5           1           1   10              92      2012-01-01
11      222         5           1           1   11              50      2012-01-01
12      222         5           1           1   12              65      2012-01-01
13      222         5           1           1   13              33      2012-01-01
7       222         5           1           1   15              86      2012-01-01
```

I want to get rank I got answer by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314471/mysql-get-rank-with-filters)

Also when I fetched all class result I use pivot query:

```
SELECT stu_id, sum(numbers) AS total, branch_id, depart_id, class_id,
 SUM( IF( subject_id =1, numbers, 0 ) ) AS MAth,
 SUM( IF( subject_id =2, numbers, 0 ) ) AS Eng,
SUM( IF( subject_id =3, numbers, 0 ) ) AS Science
FROM marksheet where branch_id = 1 AND depart_id = 1
 AND class_id = 1 GROUP BY stu_id ORDER BY total DESC
```

I want to get rank in my class query (pivot query)? And I want to count how many students on first position and how many on second and third?

Required Data sample:

```
ID      Name        Math        English     Science     Total   Percent     Position   Rank
```

Any one help?

Comment: Could you make this a subquery and perform a similar group by on the results from this one?

Comment: I can't understand every possible answer I wan

Comment: is the number the result?

Comment: If one of these two possible please answer? Get Rank with pivot query or Count rank?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need to do is create a second table with grade boundaries that are being referenced so for instance :

```
ID    grade    start_boundry    end_boundry
1       A             60            100
```

ect..

then create a join between the tables and then do a `WHERE` statement between the Numbers and the start/ end boundries

so ->

```
SELECT grade FROM boundries_table RIGHT JOIN  sudent_table
WHERE boundries_table.start_boundry < student_table.numbers
AND boundries_table.end_boundry > student_table.numbers
```

i think that should work if my MySQL memory serves, just modify the table to how you need it to run and it should work for how you need it.